# How to reload the parent frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Sample parent code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Parent</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/child.html" width="200" height="100"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in action:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B5jOXzxlxbMhYVF3b0lubjlDWm8/parent.html

Sample child code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Child</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it!</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
parent.location.reload();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried many methods offered in similar questions to no avail, such as:

```
window.parent.location.reload();  
top.location.reload();
```

etc.

What am I missing and what's the right approach?

Comment: question is not clear to me...

Comment: @Jai: When I click the button, the parent frame (the whole page) doesn't refresh.

Comment: if you could post the click event code.

Comment: does `window.parent.location = window.parent.location;` work?

Comment: @OneOfOne: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer to my question: `document.referrer`

Child:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Child</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it!</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
window.parent.location = document.referrer;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check in chrome browsers console it shows attached error,Its cross domain access issue.

see the error screen grab for the detailed information.

[image]

check out [this](http://calibrate.be/labs/cross-domain-iframe-communication) it looks helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to refresh iframe without refreshing my hole page you can use in your code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      location = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/child.html'
    },4000) // set time for refreshing iframe as you wish I used 4000 miliseconds
    </script>
```

Comment: I need to reload the parent/whole page, NOT the iframe.

Comment: then you just your page  url after location = 'here will your page url'

Comment: That's not possible in my case as the parent URL is dynamic -- it's not a fixed URL you can count on.

Answer (score -1):

you could try this

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
     window.parent.location=window.parent.location;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I actually tried it and it is working fine.. may i know what result are you getting

Comment: how can you identify whether your parent page reloaded or not since there is now data in your parent page other than the frame